# When i select the `select all` checkbox the each checkbox is not selected visually, but i can see that are selected in the state

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, state, antd

I am writing react and i have a Table component in ant design and i want to select all the records that exists in all pages and not in every page that is the default. My code is like this

```
<Table
   style={{marginTop: 10}}
   rowSelection={SelectionConfig}
   ......


 const {selectedRows} = this.state

 const SelectionConfig = {
  selectedRows,
    onSelect: (record, selected, selectedRows, nativeEvent) => {
        this.setState({selectedRows: selectedRows})
        this.props.updateFieldsToCreate(selectedRows)
  },
  columnTitle: () => {
    return(
      <div>
      <Checkbox
        checked={selectedRows.length}
        indeterminate={
          selectedRows.length > 0 &&
          selectedRows.length < this.state.polygonData.length
        }
        onChange={(e) => {
          const { checked } = e.target;
          const selectedRows = checked
            ? this.state.polygonData.map((r) => r)
            : [];
          this.setState({ selectedRows: selectedRows }, () => {
            this.props.updateFieldsToCreate(selectedRows);
          });
        }}
      />
      </div>
    )
  },
  type: "checkbox",
  fixed: true,
}
```

When i `console.log` my state`selectedRows` i can see that has data and i can sent this data to my server. But the each row seems that it is not selected only visually [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMkBj.png). I have find [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-selection-forked-r702s?file=/index.js:1576-1607) it's help me to find how to choose all the data. How i can make this visual so the user can know that has select all the rows in every page.